# Spring Boot Application gets killed when remote application gets killed

Tags: spring-boot

Scenario :

I have two Application named A and B. Both spring boot with their apis exposed. I call B from A and immediately kill B so that no response is returned to A. But unfortunately A gets killed.

So anyone have idea please share.

Comment: please provide port of both boot application

Comment: A is running on 8081 and B is remotely running on 7006